# How can I prevent weak customer passwords in Woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, security, passwords, woocommerce

I enforce strong passwords across my WordPress sites using ithemes security; however one of my sites runs Woocommerce; and allows users to create an account. There is seemingly no way that I can prevent users from using '123' or 'password' etc as a password. I tried generating the password but they can still log in and change the password and the change isn't filtered by weak/strong either.

Is there any way to do this, or am I being paranoid thinking that a customer account is something that could be used to hack the site.

Comment: https://github.com/dropbox/zxcvbn + require a score of at least 3 = solved 99% of user's weak passwords

Comment: Thanks ... I can't imagine where to start integrating that into woocommerce .. would you think it would work in conjunction with ashok's answer below ... ie use the user_register hook for instance?

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent this using user registration action hook.

`add_action( 'user_register', 'myplugin_registration_save', 10, 1 );`

and writing your restriction functions in  your functions.php

```
function myplugin_registration_save()
{
           logical code
}
```

> source : [Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register)

Comment: According to the codex "The password has already been encrypted when this action is triggered." ... is this not too late ... if it's not then I understand the idea but how would the function actually operate ... I suppose I would find and check the password and output a message if the password didn't pass criteria ... but how would I get it to stop the user and display the message. Not sure how i'd get the password to check it either

Comment: You are correct but you could try it with ajax code.

Comment: I've tried ajax before ... I can do it but it's outside of my coding ability  ... I discovered a plugin which I'm trying out, but there's a bit of a problem with it which i've raised in support .. https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-enforce-strong-password/

Comment: Hm ok, the other play around would be using javascript, for this you need to know about the field name or id. Which you can do it directly in the front end.